# How to add data from MS Access Data Entry form while maintaining the table relationship integrity

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a Student and Course Tables.

```
Student
  ID - Primary Key - AutoNumber
  CID - Number
  FirstName - Text
  LastName - Text

Course
  ID - Number
  CourseTitle - Text
```

I have a data entry sub form where I can enter a `CourseTitle`, `FirstName` and `LastName` and when I click Save Record, the data is saved to Student and Course tables. However, the second time around when I enter same course title, it adds another row with same name in course table with different ID. If I'm entering a course name that already exists then it **should not** add a new course title.

Example

Assume that before saving the record the state of data is:

```
Course
-------

ID     | CourseTitle
-------|-------------
1      | Maths

Student
-------

ID      | CID    | FirstName    | LastName
--------|--------|--------------|----------
1       | 1      | Mike         | Someone
```

Now, when I save the data from the Data Entry Form:

```
Course Name = Maths
First Name = Junior
Last Name = Someone Else
```

The state of Data becomes

```
Course
-------

ID     | CourseTitle
-------|-------------
1      | Maths
2      | Maths

Student
-------

ID      | CID    | FirstName    | LastName
--------|--------|--------------|----------
1       | 1      | Mike         | Someone
2       | 2      | Mike         | Someone
```

**Question**
However, I want the data to look like:

How can I make this happen??

```
Course
-------

ID     | CourseTitle
-------|-------------
1      | Maths

Student
-------

ID      | CID    | FirstName    | LastName
--------|--------|--------------|----------
1       | 1      | Mike         | Someone
2       | 1      | Mike         | Someone
```

Comment: Do you have student as a sub form of course? or vice-versa when doing data entry? if not, it will add separate records.

Comment: I would suggest a third table to handle the Student - Course many to many relationship. This way you can add the studentid and course id without duplicating the Student record (Unless there are two students name Mike Someone.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely will be better off if you take Jeff O's suggestion and implement this as a many-to-many relationship.

As far as the data entry form is concerned, the control for entering a course should be a combo box or a list box.  The control source binds the control to the course id field in the many-to-many table (or, in the example as you have it, to the CID field in the students table).  The control's Row Source is bound either to the courses table or to a query derived from the table.  The "bound column" should specify the course table's ID column.

It's a little confusing, because you're binding two things.  The first binding connects the control's value to a column in the form's RecordSource.  The second binding connects a column in the control's RowSource to the control's value.  The combination of the two bindings allows the user to edit the foreign key relationship for a given record by changing the control's value.

To avoid displaying the ID in the control, you would set the width of the bound column to 0.  For example, using your example above, you would enter these settings in the property sheet:

```
RowSource = Course
BoundColumn = 1
ColumnWidths = 0"
```

(Since you have two columns, but only one column width, the remainder of the unspecified width is allocated to the last column.  Since the first column width is zero, that means that the entire display width is given to the second column, so all you see in the list is the course's name.)